# Flip image after load for 1 second using css

Tags: css

I am using CSS & HTML to flip the image on hover, but how can I flip image for 1 second after loading?

Comment: please show us what you have tried. thanks

Comment: I AM NEW ON THIS PROFILE. CAN YOU PLEASE REACH ME BY     EMAIL      GENUINESAGAR@GMAIL.COM

Answer (score 0):

You can set a keyframe animation on a 1-second delay. The `forwards` makes sure the style from the animation is kept.

```
.flip {
  animation: flip-animation .25s 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: flip-animation .25s 1s forwards; /* for less modern browsers */
}

@keyframes flip-animation {
  // code to flip the
  from {}
  to{}
}
```